# Interactive Ploting

Tags: python, plot

I'm searching for an interactive pliting library. I have some dataset that I would like to plot like a scatter (if posible over an image), And need to show some information on focus (or click if focus it's not posible). Let's say for sake of the question, some number.

I don't really know if there a tool that would let me do this, without an excesive amount of code (probably I can do it myself using a canvas in tkinter).

I only have some experience in matplotlib for ploting. That's my principal limitation.

What I'm doing now is to annotate every marker with something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,3,1,1,5]
an = [10,42,3,33,4] 

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
for i,a in enumerate(an):
    plt.annotate(a, (x[i],y[i]))
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry if something isn't clear

Comment: Have a look into Plotly.

Comment: You can [embed a matplotlib plot in a tkinter canvas](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html)

Comment: thanks @S3DEV i will. Jezza_99 that's exactly what i'm trying to avoid!